# Changing colour of object when following path

Tags: animation, objects, shaders

I would like to change the colour of my Mball according to the value of the z-Coordinate. The Mball is following a path.

[image: Path and Mball]

Usually I would do it with this node configuaration: get the Location of the object, take the Z value, using a Map Range and ColorRamp and use this colour.
[image: Shading nodes Mball]

However, the colour of the Mball always stays the same. Apparently, the Mball object coordinates do not change when following a path...

So how could I achieve this?

[image]